# Affiliate link inside on iframe - cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe

I have an idea where I want to have affiliate URL (website) embedded inside of iframe
(for example https://www.asos.com/?affid=1234)
Once I visit it, I will have affid saved inside of cookies. Navigating in new tab to asos.com, affid cookie will be there.

Is it possible to do the same with iframe?

Current setup:

```
<iframe src="https://www.asos.com/?affid=4321" />
```

Checking cookies on my website (where iframe is placed), there isn't affid cookie, also when checking asos.com, there is still previously visited affid (1234).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need some js. Cross-domain Iframes are technically prohibited in HTML5, but you can use porthole.js to do it. Porthole.js is a very useful library, I have used it several times.
porthole's docs: https://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/